# Delete a mongo document using the $http web interface for mongoDB in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

New to Angular and MongoDB here, I've been trying out the $http interface (using the mongod --rest command) for mongodb in my local machine in angularjs and I am unable to delete a document using the given command. I've used this snippet in my controller file

```
var delete= $http.delete('http://127.0.0.1:28017/databasename/collectionname',{"name":$scope.name});
```

Now, I have verified that inserting and querying documents work properly so it's just a problem with deleting documents. Likewise, I am having trouble with findandmodify as well. Any help will be appreciated. I used the following to insert:

```
var p = $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:28017/databasename/collectionname/insert', $scope.inserttodatabase);
```

Edit: Added Code for insert

Comment: Can you post the code used for insert operation?

Comment: I added an edit. Thank you

Comment: Does it throw any error?

Comment: It says "don't know how to handle a [DELETE]" in the command prompt

Comment: Please add delete script for mongodb